# React - Bug for resizing div

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-hooks, resize

I am learning ReactJS and I started a small project to learn it.
I try to create a div which is able to be resized by dragging it.
This is my code :

```
import { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import PostViewer from '../PostViewer/PostViewer';
import './ContainerResize.scss'
import * as htmlToImage from 'html-to-image';
import { toPng } from 'html-to-image';
import download from 'downloadjs'


function savePng() {
    htmlToImage.toPng(document.getElementById('Resizable'))
        .then(function (dataUrl) {
            download(dataUrl, 'tweet.png');
        });
}

const ContainerResize = (props) => {

    const [initialPos, setInitialPos] = useState(null);
    const [initialSize, setInitialSize] = useState(null);
    const resizable = useRef(null);

    const initial = (e) => {
        setInitialPos(e.clientX);
        setInitialSize(resizable.current.offsetWidth);
        console.log(resizable.current.offsetWidth)
    }

    const resizeLeft = (e) => {
        resizable.current.style.width = `${parseInt(initialSize) + parseInt(initialPos - e.clientX)}px`;
    }

    const resizeRight = (e) => {
        resizable.current.style.width = `${parseInt(initialSize) + parseInt(e.clientX - initialPos)}px`;
    }

    return (
        <div className="containerResize">
            <button onClick={savePng}>Save</button>
            <div
                id="Draggable"
                draggable="true"
                onDragStart={initial}
                onDrag={resizeLeft}
            />
            <div id="Resizable" ref={resizable}>
                <PostViewer tweetParam={props.tweetParam} />
            </div>
            <div
                id="Draggable"
                draggable="true"
                onDragStart={initial}
                onDrag={resizeRight}
            />
        </div>
    );
}

export default ContainerResize;
```

The resize on right works fine but the resize on left doesn't work. Indeed, when i drag with the left side, the div is resized correctly but when I drop the button, the div retake its initial position.

Have you got a solution to my issue please ?

Thanks a lot for your responses :)

Comment: Hello, can you make a codes sand box of your code

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/quizzical-brahmagupta-9twhjf?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a super annoying bug. the issue is that when the mouse is released during onDrag the event is fired with `event.clientX` being set to 0.

a quick fix to this would be to check if `event.clientX === 0` and return out of the function.

Comment: Thank you so much, i took many hours to try to solve it :)